# Convert rgb decimals to RGB integers with xcolor

Tags: color

Using `xcolor` I have a color `ared` defined as in the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[names,dvipsnames,named]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ared}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}

\begin{document}

\huge\textsf{\textbf{\textcolor{ared}{HELLO}}}.

\end{document}
```

*Question:* How do I find the 3-element integer equivalent of that color?

*The reason I ask:* I want to use an app to find other colors that harmonize with that reddish color, but to do so they demand I specify the red as a triple of integers.

I tried to do this using a "color picker" app, but when I display a blob of the color on-screen as LaTeX output, the meter gives me rather different decimal values from the .647,.129,.149 I actually start with.

*Note:* This particular red was shown in the source for `memoir`'s chapter style `pederson" by Lars Madsen in the 2006 package from`/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles`. And the`memoir`documentation`memman`credits Madsen for that "attractive color" for chapter numbers and titles in the`pederson` style. (Thank you David Carlisle for locating the link to Madsen for me.)

Comment: Well, you just have to multiply the `0--1` decimals by 255 and round the result to get the RGB coefficients.  See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Color_Models. `\definecolor{aredRGB}{RGB}{165,33,38}` should be equivalent to your previous color definition

Comment: @BambOo: Thank you!

Comment: you can use `\convertcolorspec`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537264/2388

Answer (score 3):

As commented, you can use `\convertcolorspec`,  but for check the values of several colors with several color models, nothing better than the `testcolors` environment:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[names,svgnames,dvipsnames,named]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ared}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\begin{document}
\begin{testcolors}[RGB,HTML,HSB]
\testcolor{ared}
\testcolor{DarkRed}
\end{testcolors}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is `DarkRed` defined?

Comment: @murray In the  `svgnames` option