# Who defined the color "ared" as rgb .647,.129,.149?

Tags: color

Somewhere I read a (La)TeX article, possibly in TUGBoat, that mentions a certain "especially nice" red named `ared`, namely, the defined as in the source below and appearing in the output shown.

*Question:* Who created this particular color and in what journal, book, web posting, etc.?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ared}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{ared}{\rule{0pt}{18pt}\hspace*{24pt}} \, an especially nice red

\end{document}
```

[image: ared color]

*Why I want to know:* I, too, especially like this color for section headings, as it's not *too* red and seems to work well against the document's otherwise black text font.

In [Convert rgb decimals to RGB integers with xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544452/convert-rgb-decimals-to-rgb-integers-with-xcolor) I asked a question about using this color, and so I'd like to credit the color's "inventor" there.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @egreg: I hope so! I beg slight indulgence, since, it's likely that the color's creator is a follower of tex.stackexchange who might provide the answer. Not sure where else the question would get exposure to somebody who knows.

Comment: simple google search shows it in this 2010 document on memoir styles (pederson) http://www.ebookation.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/memoirchapstyles.pdf so it goes back at least that far

Comment: This is very close  to `Red4!85` (`x11names`).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Of course I did a web search before asking! I just did not find anything, evidently by failing to include the decimal rgb specs in my search. Thank you!

Comment: @murray actually the trick is to put ared in quotes, the link I gave was third hit I got for `\definecolor "ared"` and most of the others were "good" including your question being returned

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I finally found it, too but without using the quotes, as the 6th hit with search `\definecolor ared .647 .129 .149`. But yes quoting with `"ared"` moved the relevant hit up.